# Program stuck in loop while checking value is int or string

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find that entered value from the user is String or Int,but program stuck in a loop when a user entered any string.Can I delete `int taxableIncome`value one-time execution if yes then how ?
I'm beginner level programmer...
tell me anyway within that I can check Value from user is int or string....
here is code

```
int taxableIncome;

for (;;) {
    cout << "Please enter in your taxable income: ";
    if (cin >> taxableIncome) {
        cout << "Your income: " << taxableIncome;
        break;
    } else {
        cout << "Please enter a valid integer" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: "delete taxableIncome" - this is completely bogus. "taxableIncome" was not allocated with `new`. It is not even a pointer. Does that even compile??

Comment: "Ur income" - if you can't even be bothered to spell "Your" correctly then I can't be bothered to look at your code any more..

Comment: Oh that was my last try to run program.....i have removed it now...thanx

Comment: Ok Your income....

Answer (score 3):

Once `cin >> taxableIncome` fails (which you're detecting) further reads from `cin` will fail directly because the stream is already flagged with its `bad` bit. You need to clear that bit, munch the rest of the line, and try again.

```
int taxableIncome;

for (;;) {
    cout << "Please enter in your taxable income: ";
    if (cin >> taxableIncome) {
        cout << "Your income: " << taxableIncome;
        break;
    } else {
        cout << "Please enter a valid integer" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the use of the technical term, *munch*.  + 1